# How to update image source with respond to a press event

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a touchableOpacity component contains some .png picture file, I want to change one of the image source and bind the change event to the onPress event. I current initialize the source as a prop in getInitialState() like

```
source: require('someSource.png')
```

and implement

```
this.setState({source: require('someOtherSource.png')});
```

to the onPress function. Somehow the image size is changed accordingly because I added resizeMode: 'contain' to the image style. But the second image file did not load onto the view.
The part where the Image view:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.newUserRegister}
                    onPress={this.doRegister}>
                <Image style={styles.accNewUser} source={this.state.source}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and in the doRegister() function:

```
this.setState({source: require('someOtherSource.png')});
```

I have three states of the image source so I thought call the setState function in doRegister might be a better solution.

Also in case if it is the problem with styling, this is the styles for accNewUser

```
accNewUser:{
    marginTop:5,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context?

Comment: @Klaasman I've added more details

Comment: is the `doRegister` method bound to the component's scope? Otherwise the method is called with a wrong scope which doesn't provide the `setState` of the component.  

Something else what popped my mind: try importing dependencies outside your component, e.g. `const someOtherSourceImg = require('someOtherSource.png')` and use it as `this.setState({source: someOtherSourceImg}); `

Comment: @Klaasman it is binded because I put some console.log() into the doRegister function and it worked.  The view initialization works fine, but image is still not loading properly

Answer (score 0):

I did this example for your case: https://rnplay.org/apps/jePI5Q

Unfortunately RNPlay doesn't allow adding assets, so I had to use external images with `uri` reference. Just replace those references with `require(<asset>)` and you'll be fine.

That example has toggling the state between `defaultSource` (arrow up) and the other one (arrow down).

Comment: I actually have three states of the image source and I can see the changes in image size but the image itself is not really loaded to the right source